# Python raise - SyntaxError when running as an executable

Tags: python

When I run my .py file from terminal I got no error, but when I run in as an executable (the exact same app) I get an error on this line

```
raise RuntimeError(f'Line lengths in the {file} are not ok. Please check it.')
```

When I comment it out it works. The error is: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing to the `'` symbol at the end of the line. I do not understand how is it possible the file works without an error when running from terminal but not when run as executable.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: That is the line causing the error.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.4

Comment: Oh yeah I see.. It looks like I am running the file from IDE with python 3.7.4 but when running as an executable ```python``` command is assigned to python 2.7... that would be probably it.. omg

Comment: In which  python version are your .exe being executed?

Comment: That is it man, f-string are for python versions >= python 3.6, just change f-string formating to str.format .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I am sorry - my stupid bad.
When I was running the file from "terminal" - IDE used python 3.7.4 but when I run it as an (macOS) executable the default `python` command was using python 2.7.

So I just changed first line of the app to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or one may also change alias for python.